# Change an Element to an Attribute PHP/DOM (XML)

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am looking to try and change a XML output so that the element structure changes and some CDATA becomes an `attribute` rather than an `<element>`

Given the XML `stack.xml`:

```
<root>
  <item>
    <name>name</name>
    <type>Type</type>
    <dateMade>Datemade</dateMade>
    <desc>Desc</desc>
  </item>
 ....(more Items)...
</root>
```

I would like to change the XML output to `stacksaved.xml`:

```
<root>
  <item>
    <name>name</name>
    <Itemtype type="Type">
        <Itemdate dateMade="Datemade">
            <desc>Desc</desc>
        </Itemdate>
    <Itemtype>
  </item>
 ....(next item)....
</root>
```

So far my PHP DOM looks like this:

```
<?php
    //create and load
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load('stack.xml');

    $types=$doc->getElementsByTagName("type");
    foreach ($types as $type)
    {
        $attribute=$doc->getElementsByTagName("type");
        $doc->getElementsByTagName("type").setAttribute("$attribute"); 
    }
    $doc->save('stacksaved.xml'); //save the final results into xml file
?>
```

I keep getting the error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function setAttribute() and the document is not saved or edited in anyway. I am really new to DOM/PHP and would greatly appreciate any advice!

How would I go about changing the **child structure** and the **element** to the desired output?

Thanks as always for the read!

**EDIT:** Parfait gave a great explanation and showed the great power of XSLT but I am trying to get this to run using pure php only as a learning exercise for php/DOM. Can anyone help with converting this using PHP only?

Comment: Do not change the original, build a new target document with the information from the source document. Use `DOMXpath::evaluate()` to fetch data from the source document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a *pure* PHP DOM solution, consider creating a new `DOMDocument` iterating over values of old document using `createElement`, `appendChild`, and `setAttribute` methods. The multiple nested `if` logic is needed to check existence of a node before creating elements with items' node values, otherwise *Undefined Warnings* are raised.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('stack.xml');

// INITIALIZE NEW DOM DOCUMENT
$newdoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$newdoc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$newdoc->formatOutput = true;

// APPEND ROOT
$root= $newdoc->appendChild($newdoc->createElement("root"));

$items=$doc->getElementsByTagName("item");

// ITERATIVELY APPEND ITEM AND CHILDREN
foreach($items as $item){    
    $ItemNode = $newdoc->createElement("item");
    $root->appendChild($ItemNode);

    if (count($item->getElementsByTagName("name")->item(0)) > 0) {
        $ItemNode->appendChild($newdoc->createElement('name', $item->getElementsByTagName("name")->item(0)->nodeValue));
    }

    if (count($item->getElementsByTagName("type")->item(0)) > 0) {        
        $ItemtypeNode = $ItemNode->appendChild($newdoc->createElement('Itemtype'));
        $ItemtypeNode->setAttribute("type", $item->getElementsByTagName("type")->item(0)->nodeValue);

        if (count($item->getElementsByTagName("dateMade")->item(0)) > 0) {
            $ItemdateNode = $ItemtypeNode->appendChild($newdoc->createElement('Itemdate'));
            $ItemdateNode->setAttribute("dateMade", $item->getElementsByTagName("dateMade")->item(0)->nodeValue);

            if (count($item->getElementsByTagName("desc")->item(0)) > 0) {
                $ItemdateNode->appendChild($newdoc->createElement('desc', $item->getElementsByTagName("desc")->item(0)->nodeValue));
            }
        }

    }
}

// ECHO AND SAVE NEW DOC TREE
echo $newdoc->saveXML();
$newdoc->save($cd.'/ItemTypeDateMade_dom.xml');
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>name</name>
    <Itemtype type="Type">
      <Itemdate dateMade="Datemade">
        <desc>Desc</desc>
      </Itemdate>
    </Itemtype>
  </item>
</root>
```

---

As mentioned in previous answer, here requires `for` and nested `if` that would not be required with XSLT. In fact, using `microtime`, we can compare script runtimes. Below enlargen `stack.xml`:

```
$time_start = microtime(true); 
...
echo "Total execution time in seconds: " . (microtime(true) - $time_start) ."\n";
```

At 1,000 node lines, XSLT proves faster than DOM:

```
# XSLT VERSION
Total execution time in seconds: 0.0062189102172852

# DOM VERSION
Total execution time in seconds: 0.013695955276489
```

At 2,000 node lines, XSLT still remains about 2X faster than DOM:

```
# XSLT VERSION
Total execution time in seconds: 0.014697074890137

# DOM VERSION
Total execution time in seconds: 0.031282186508179
```

At 10,000 node lines, XSLT now becomes slightly faster than DOM. Reason for DOM's catch up might be due to the memory inefficiency XSLT 1.0 maintains for larger files, especially (> 100 MB). But arguably here for this use case, the XSLT approach is an easier PHP script to maintain and read:

```
# XSLT VERSION
Total execution time in seconds: 0.27568817138672

# DOM VERSION
Total execution time in seconds: 0.37149095535278
```

Comment: thanks so much for the added help and info. It's amazing to see the speed difference of a large process and can see how XSLT is a much more efficient option. Thanks again! Have a great day. :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose, declarative language designed to transform XML documents. PHP can run XSLT 1.0 scripts with the [`php-xsl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) extension (be sure to enable it in .ini file). With this approach, you avoid any need of `foreach` looping or `if` logic.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="root">   
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
   </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>    

  <xsl:template match="item">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
     <Itemtype type="{type}">
      <Itemdate dateMade="{dateMade}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="desc"/>   
      </Itemdate>
     </Itemtype>    
   </xsl:copy>   
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**PHP**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('stack.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('XSLTScript.xsl');

// CONFIGURE TRANSFORMER
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 

// PROCESS TRANSFORMATION
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($doc);

// ECHO STRING OUTPUT
echo $newXML;

// SAVE OUTPUT TO FILE
file_put_contents('Output.xml', $newXML);
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>name</name>
    <Itemtype type="Type">
      <Itemdate dateMade="Datemade">
        <desc>Desc</desc>
      </Itemdate>
    </Itemtype>
  </item>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @parfait ! XSLT is a great transformation tool, but I am trying to learn how to do this via pure PHP without an external XSL file. Is this possible?

Comment: That would still work. You can store the XSLT as a string inside the script and use `DOMDocument::loadXml()` to load it.

Comment: Indeed, XSLT is a well-formed XML file and can be parsed from string or file.